# Fill DropdownList with data from database MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi there as the question states I have 3 different tables with data in them;

The first table (type):

```
id    type
1     Day
2     Month
3     Year
```

The second table (server):

```
server
Europe
Asia
North America
South America
```

The third table (status)

```
status
Error
Verified
```

I have to create a log with 3 drop menus that are required and I thought it would be much easier and easier to update with more information later on if I would will the dropdropmenu with data from the database.

This is my AddLogModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ReviewLogs.Models
{
    public class AddLogModel
    {

        [Display(Name = "Type: "),
        Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public List<string> type { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Server: "),
        Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public List<string> server { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status: "),
        Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public List<string> status { get; set; }


    }
}
```

And My Main Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddLogReview(AddLogModel model)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                using (var db = new reviewlogsEntities())
                {



                }

            }

            else
            {
                //Honestly I don't think this will ever be hit but lets just be safe
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Required Data Not Filled In");
            }

            return View(model);

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }
    }
```

How would I go about getting the 3 tables info from my database into 3 seperate dropdown lists. I can't change the tables layout, I was given this database. Could you also show how the view would look as well? I really appreciate it!

### Heading

Comment: You should really be having 3 different model class targeting 3 different DB entities and then you can use scaffold template / generate dropdown view binding the DB value to your drodownlist.

Comment: @Rahul Could you explain in a bit more detail I'm not sure I understand

Comment: A dropdownlist binds to a single value, so your model (view model) needs a property for the selected value and the collection (to generate the options) for each dropdownlist. Its not clear what your wanting to do in the POST method - do you want to save the 3 selected values from the dropdownlists (say `2`, `"North America"` and `"Verified"` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have a model like

```
public class Server
{
    [Display(Name = "Server: ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string server { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, you can then get the list of server and pass it to view

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Models.Server> serverList = new List<Models.Server>()
        {
            new Server {server = "abc"}, 
            new Server {server = "xyz"}, 
            new Server {server = "def"}
        };
        return View(serverList);
    }
```

In view get the dropdown

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Select(s => s.server), 
                            Model.Select(s => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                 Text = s.server, Value = s.server
                            }))
```

Where model is `@model IEnumerable<Models.Server>`